# Espaço vazio entre colunas no Frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, grid

Eu estou criando uma aplicação utilizando `tkinter` e o método `.grid()`. Na minha janela, eu tenho dois frames, um para widgets relacionados ao *input* do usuário e outro para o *output*.

No frame de *input*, eu quero que os widgets `Label` e o `Menubutton` fiquem na mesma *row*, no entanto, ambos nas extremidades da janela — `Label` alinhado à esquerda e `Menubutton` alinhado à direita. Abaixo está o meu código:

```
from tkinter import Frame, Menu, Text, Tk, Label
from tkinter.ttk import Button, Entry, Menubutton

class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self, title = "Binary Converter"):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.resizable(False, False)

    def build(self):
        # Cria widgets relacionados ao input do usuário.
        input_frame = Frame(self)
        input_frame.grid(row = 0, padx = 10, pady = 20, sticky = "w")

        self.__input_label = Label(input_frame, text = "Valor a ser convertido: ", font = ("Helvetica", 12))
        self.__input_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "w")

        self.__options = Menubutton(input_frame, text = "Converter para:")
        self.__options.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "e")

        self.__input = Entry(input_frame, width = 80, font = ("Helvetica", 10))
        self.__input.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "w")

        # Cria widgets relacionados ao output da aplicação.
        output_frame = Frame(self)
        output_frame.grid(row = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky = "w")

        self.__output_label = Label(output_frame, text = "O valor convertido aparecerá abaixo:", font = ("Helvetica", 12))
        self.__output_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "w")

        self.__output = Text(output_frame, width = 80, height = 5, font = ("Helvetica", 10))
        self.__output.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
```

O problema, como vocês podem ver se executarem o código, é que o widget `Menubutton` acaba "vazando" da tela. Eu adicionei um *background* ao `Frame`, para ver o comportamento dos widgets, e pude notar que há um espaço vazio enorme entre o `Label` e o `Menubutton`.

Curiosamente, esse espaço vazio some quando eu removo o `Entry` que está na segunda *row*, logo abaixo desses widgets.

O que está acontecendo e como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não sei se entendi exatamente o que você quer dizer com "vazando da tela", mas eu imagino que você queira que tanto o Label quanto o Menubutton estejam em cima da Entry. Se for isso, então você está entendendo errado como o `grid` do tkinter funciona. No grid, o tamanho da coluna ou da linha é determinado pelo maior elemento dentro daquela coluna ou linha. No seu caso, tanto o Entry como o Text tem width 80, forçando que a coluna 0 do seu Frame tenha largura 80. O Menubutton está na coluna 1, por isso ele está distante do Label. Existem várias formas de resolver isso, eu vou de dar duas.

A primeira e mais obvia é fazer com que o Entry e o Text ocupem duas colunas (a coluna 0 e a coluna 1). Para isso você usa, dentro do grud deles o comando `columnspam=2`:

```
    self.__input = Entry(input_frame, width = 80, font = ("Helvetica", 10))
    self.__input.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan=2)
```

O segundo, um pouco mais complicado, mas mais poderoso, é você criar um frame na sua linha 0, coluna 0, e dentro desse frame você coloca tanto o Label quanto o Entry:

```
    aux_frame = Frame(input_frame)
    aux_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "we")
    aux_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.__input_label = Label(aux_frame, text = "Valor a ser convertido: ", font = ("Helvetica", 12))
    self.__input_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "w")

    self.__options = Menubutton(aux_frame, text = "Converter para:")
    self.__options.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "e")
```

repare que aqui eu precisei usar o `columnconfigure` no frame auxiliar pra dar um peso pra coluna zero. Isso é necessário pro tkinter saber como dividir o espaço que estiver sobrando no Frame. Outra coisa importante de chamar atenção é que nesse caso você sequer precisaria usar o grid. Poderia usar o pack tanto pros elementos no frame principal quanto no auxiliar.